# How do I publish a nuget package from a linux machine?

Tags: .net, linux, nuget, nuget-package, build-server

If I'm using `dotnet pack` to produce my nuget package on a linux build server, what steps need to be taken to then make the package consumable on nuget?

Answer (score 3):

I found out that the .NET Core Tools version RC4 includes a command to publish a nuget package.

```
dotnet nuget push [<package>]
```

It provides options to include your api-key, publishing symbols and different verbosity levels.

The .Net core Tools Version RC4 also provides two additional nuget operations

- dotnet nuget delete, to unlist a package from a server
- dotnet nuget locals, to manage the temporary nuget cache.

You can find the rest of the information here:
[dotnet-nuget-push](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/preview3/tools/dotnet-nuget-push)